# Which view is the "Current view"?

Tags: list, list-view

I have got a SharePoint 2010 website with a WebPart-page and a few WebParts on it.  One of the WebParts displays a list/a view of a list.  The views of that list have been updated due to business needs - but the view in the WebPart on the WebPart-page is not updated.

If I edit "Modify Shared Web Part" (the one with the list / list view),  the "Selected view" is set to "<Current view>".

My question is now: Which view of the list is the "<Current view>"?
Is it any view of the list at all - or has the WebPart some kind of its own view to that list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not updated when you change the view on the list itself.  You have to update the view on the web part.

Current View is simply the current view of the list web part.  It is the default name given to the view that is used when the list web part is added to the page.  Editing / Modifying the view on the web part will not affect the views on the list itself.

If you create a custom view on the list, you can select that as the basis for the web part view, but again changes to the view on the list itself will not be reflected on the web part or vice versa.

Comment: so there are 3 kinds of views: the custom views, the private views and the views inside of ListView-WebParts- correct?

Comment: I guess you could look at that way, yes.  All those views are independent of each other.

Comment: Is there any way to check which view (name) is selected among say 10 views for the List View Webpart?

Comment: @DebarunSana I spent a few days trying and I don't believe there is any guaranteed way because `<current view>` doesn't actually have a view name -- I have no idea WHY they made it that way, but oh well. What you can do is `edit current view` and compare those view settings to your other views and see what it matches up to.